# Optimization of Spark Streaming code with multiple windows

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have the following code snippet in my Spark Streaming application:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("EventProcessor").setMaster("local[*]");
try (JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(300))) {
    try (SparkSession spark = new SparkSession(javaStreamingContext.ssc().sc())) {

        System.out.println(CommonUtils.buildTabLog("Loaded configs", "environment", environment, "configs", ZConfig.instance.getConfigs()));
        JavaReceiverInputDStream<TEvent> eventsStream = javaStreamingContext.receiverStream(
                new RabbitMQReceiver()
        );

        eventsStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            if (rdd.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }

            Dataset<Row> eventsDs = spark.createDataFrame(rdd.map(Event::new), Event.class);

            eventsDs = eventsDs.filter(functions.col("property").equalTo(true));
            eventsDs = eventsDs.withColumn("timestamp", new Column("timestamp").cast("timestamp"));

            Dataset<Row> allPlugsDs = null;
            for (int sliceMinutes : Arrays.asList(1, 5, 15, 60, 120)) {
                Dataset<Row> plugsDs = eventsDs.groupBy(
                        functions.window(eventsDs.col("timestamp"), sliceMinutes + " minutes", sliceMinutes + " minutes"),
                        eventsDs.col("houseId"),
                        eventsDs.col("householdId"),
                        eventsDs.col("plugId")
                ).agg(functions.avg("value").as("avgLoad"),
                        functions.sum("value").as("sumLoad"),
                        functions.count("*").cast("int").as("count"));

                plugsDs = plugsDs.withColumn("sliceMinutes", functions.lit(sliceMinutes))
                        .withColumn("startTime", plugsDs.col("window.start"))
                        .withColumn("endTime", plugsDs.col("window.end"));

                if (allPlugsDs == null) {
                    allPlugsDs = plugsDs;
                } else {
                    allPlugsDs = allPlugsDs.union(plugsDs);
                }
            }

            // Upsert allPlugsDs to database
        });

        javaStreamingContext.start();
        try {
            javaStreamingContext.awaitTermination();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Spark Streaming and I want to group the data based on multiple windows, but it seems to be running quite slow. I would like to optimize this code for better performance.

Are there any recommendations or best practices to optimize Spark Streaming code with multiple windows? I'm particularly interested in improving the speed and efficiency of the groupBy operation.

Thank you for your help!

Note: I have an idea to group data based on a 1-minute window then cache them, and then group the data again based on a 5-minute window computed from the data of the 1-minute window, and then continue this process with 15-minute, 50-minute, and 120-minute windows.

Comment: Please migrate to [Spark Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) as soon as possible as this is the streaming module that gets the support from the project's devs.